# Azure AD Dynamic Group based on Group Membership

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to create an Azure AD dynamic group based on the user's other group memberships, or can it only be dynamically assigned based on user properties?

What I would like to create is an "Everyone" type group that will include everyone *except* users that are in an ExceptionGroup. This is for O365 licensing, so by default all users will get a base O365 license, but users that need Project will have a different license applied.

(The reason it needs to be completely separate is because of a conflict between the SharePoint licenses required for O365 Business Premium and Project -- if there was another way around that part of the problem, I might be able to avoid this type of dynamic group.)

Comment: Suggestions for a better way to approach the licensing issue are also welcome, recognizing that it isn't a direct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Philippe is correct that you cannot *directly* create a query that uses group membership as a criteria, but if you are syncing your Azure AD against an on-premise ActiveDirectory environment, you can certainly use scheduled scripts to put values into the extensionAttributeX fields, and then build criteria based upon those without issues.

We needed to use the distinguishedName parameter to create dynamic groups based on OU membership, but the DN field is also not supported.  So, using a scheduled job running a Powershell script I update the value of extensionAttribute9 to the DN if it has changed, and then our Azure Connect synchronization takes care of getting that data into Azure AD for the dynamic group member assignment.

An example of a Powershell script to do that for a group membership would look something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$exclude = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "excludeGroup" -Recursive | select -ExpandProperty SamaccountName
$population = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true}

foreach($p in $population) {
    if (-not $exclude.Contains($p.SamAccountName)) { Set-ADUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute4 = "Good"} }
}
```

Put that into a script that you run on a scheduled basis and then you create your dynamic Azure AD group membership based on the value in extensionAttribute4 (or whichever extensionAttribute you are not already using or prefer).

Do make sure you are syncing those fields between your local AD and Azure AD, but IIRC those are in the default set.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible to use group membership as a part of the query for a dynamic group.